# Is there a way to register on my Drupal site with mobile number and password instead of email?

Tags: users

Is there a way to register on my Drupal site with mobile number and password instead of email?

I would like to have my users register on my Drupal site with either mobile number and password or email and password. The confirmation code is sent to the corresponding destination and the user is activated.

Comment: How do you send SMS messages to your users?

Comment: I have a SMS gateway API. I am planning to use wsclient module for sending SMS.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible, but you will have a lot of work to do it.

First thing first, you need a way to communicate with your users. Drupal sends quite a lot of data to users, like password restoration mails. If you want phone numbers to replace mail, you need to be able to send SMS messages. [SMS Framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/smsframework) seems to be your friend here. There is no stable version for Drupal 7, but as far as I know it is most stable at the moment anyway.

When you have a way to communicate using their mobile numbers, you need to override mail sending, to convert mails into SMS messages. There are, generally, two ways to achieve this:

1. [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) - It is possible to configure mailserver to send sms messages if address is in *phone_number*@sms.local or similar format. This does not even require any SMS framework in Drupal, really.
2. Use [Mail System](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem) and create your own  [`MailSystemInterface`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/interface/MailSystemInterface/7) implementation that will detect sms addresses and use [SMS Framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/smsframework) instead of whatever mail system you are using.

If you don't want to mess with mail systems, you will need to effectively write user module from scratch and replace core one with your own - it relies on mails too much, writing `alter`s would not be feasible.

Last thing: For all Drupal forms, you need to use form alter and detect required email, changing it into two fields, at least one required. And provide relevant storage. Actually, this seems to be an easy part.

**Note** pretty much every modern phone can receive emails, so I hardly see a point in this.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder whether there is a way for Drupal to "read" the visitor's phone number and paste it into the appropriate field automatically.

Comment: @iantresman Wrong question - you should be asking 'is there a way for _a website_ to "read" the visitor's phone number'. Drupal is essentially a glorified HTML generator, it can't do anything that HTML/CSS/JS can't do. Either way I think you'll find the answer is "no". The privacy quarter would have gone mental about it by now if an arbitrary web page was able to scrape a user's phone number without their explicit permission

Comment: @Clive Do you know of any email to sms gateway for D7? There is one, but it does not even have a dev release. https://www.drupal.org/project/sms_email_gateway

Comment: Also wanted to point out https://www.drupal.org/project/phone_registration which takes care of the registration form part.

Dev release: https://www.drupal.org/project/phone_registration/releases/8.x-1.x-dev
Code: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/phone_registration

It does not seem to be maintained but it is currently easy to [become a maintainer of the module](https://www.drupal.org/project/phone_registration/issues/3235670).