# Login by phone or email along with Username

Tags: 7, users

There is a requirement to provide login option with all the following: username, email and phone. I understand [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) provides the capability to login with email or username. I am looking to incorporate the phone number as well, is there a module which would let the user do this?

I did see some posts in Drupal answers too but all of them discuss only about email login.

**Edit**: The forum suggests me to edit my question with more details about the [cross referenced stackExchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138980/is-there-a-way-to-register-on-my-drupal-site-with-mobile-number-and-password-ins) post. Registering the user's phone number is definitely something which has to be considered, however, the prerequisite for me is to check whether phone login is possible in first case which will work seamlessly with email login and username login. A multiple provision would not be bad especially for people like me with poor memory ;)

Comment: looks different to me in terms of registration/login, in case if we are not altering registration process to have registration with phone and only login is to have login by another field, alt_login (https://www.drupal.org/project/alt_login) can be a potential candidate.

Comment: Alternate Login looks promising, thanks for that, will explore on it.